# React/Redux Router.transitionTo is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router, redux

I can't figure out how to redirect inside the `re-base` `post` callback in my component.

https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base#postendpoint-options

I am using `re-base` to persist data to Firebase. I am using Redux for the store.

I tried passing the router via the context but it didn't help.

This is the error I get

```
main.js:344 Uncaught TypeError: Router.transitionTo is not a function
```

These are my imports ( I know there's a mix of different styles )

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
const ReactRouter = require('react-router');
const Router = ReactRouter.Router;
const Route = ReactRouter.Route;
const Navigation = ReactRouter.Navigation;
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';
const history = createBrowserHistory();
const h = require('./helpers');
const Link = require('react-router').Link;

const Rebase = require('re-base');
const base = Rebase.createClass('https://paulwp-polls-fcc.firebaseio.com');
const _ = require('underscore');
import { syncReduxAndRouter, routeReducer } from 'redux-simple-router';
const Redux = require('redux');
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
const createStore = Redux.createStore;
const combineReducers = Redux.combineReducers;
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
```

Here is my component :

```
const VoteOnPoll = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        const { store } = this.context;
        this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() =>
            this.forceUpdate()
        );
        this.choicesRef = base.listenTo('paulwp/choices', {
            context: this,
            asArray: true,
            then(choicesData){
                choicesData.map(function(choice){
                    store.dispatch({
                        type: 'LOAD_CHOICE',
                        choice: choice
                    })
                })

            }
        })
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        this.unsubscribe();
    },
    handleClick: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const { store } = this.context;
        var state = store.getState();
        var choiceID = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
        var choice = _.findWhere(state.choices,{id:choiceID});
        choice.voteTally += 1;
        store.dispatch({
           type: 'CAST_VOTE',
            choice: choice
        });

        var pollID =this.props.params.pollID;
        base.post('paulwp/choices/' + choice.id, {

            data: {desc: choice.desc, pollID: choice.pollID, voteTally: choice.voteTally},
            then(){
                Router.transitionTo('public/polls/results/poll-1449093953412');
            }
        });
    },

    render: function(){
        const { store } = this.context;
        var state = store.getState();
        var poll = _.findWhere(state.polls,{id:this.props.params.pollID});
        var choices = _.where(state.choices,{pollID:this.props.params.pollID});
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {choices.map((choice,index) => {
                        return <li key={index}><a onClick={this.handleClick} href="#" data-id={choice.id}>{choice.desc}</a></li>
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
VoteOnPoll.contextTypes = {
    store: React.PropTypes.object
};
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: What version of react-router? < 1.0.0?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I forgot I was using Redux Simple Router :)
So the answer is in the documentation:
https://github.com/jlongster/redux-simple-router

I just needed to use

```
store.dispatch(updatePath('/public/polls/results/poll-1449093953412'))
```

instead of react-router methods